# How do I remove double quotes from string PHP?

Tags: php

I use this but not working, returns same value (`$teamdatarow['color1']`)
`$color1 = str_replace('&quot;', '', $teamdatarow['color1']);`

Comment: Do you want to remove `&quot;` or `"` ?

Comment: Most likely it's being sent `"` than `&quot;`

Comment: ...I'm actually suspicious of this question: Why do you think you need to remove them and why are they there in the first place? Can you give some context?

Answer (score 2):

Just try with:

```
$color1 = str_replace('"', '', $teamdatarow['color1']);
```